# android navigation Drawer button not working

Tags: java, android

In my android application I am using "navigation drawer"..
 I have **"BaseActivity.java"**

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    protected RelativeLayout _completeLayout, _activityLayout;
    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.drawer);

        // displayView(0);



        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);



    }

    public void set(String[] navMenuTitles, TypedArray navMenuIcons) {
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();
        // adding nav drawer items
        if (navMenuIcons == null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < navMenuTitles.length; i++) {
                navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[i]));
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < navMenuTitles.length; i++) {
                navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[i],
                        navMenuIcons.getResourceId(i, -1)));
            }
        }
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter






        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, // nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for
                // accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for
        // accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    }

    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
            }
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /***
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        // boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        // menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();// finishes the current activity
            break;
        case 1:
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
            finish();// finishes the current activity
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

and my **"FirstActivity.java"** is:--

```
FirstActivity extends BaseActivity {

    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_test);


        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items); 

        navMenuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);
        set(navMenuTitles, navMenuIcons);
    }

}
```

and the **SecondActivity.java** is same as **"FirstActivity.java"**..

But when I run the application, It only showing FirstActivity..and navigation button(drawer) is not working.no any error is also occuring..can anyone tell me where is the problem????

Comment: what is set(navMenuTitles, navMenuIcons); in FirstActivity.java?

Comment: FirstActivity extends BaseActivity ..And in BaseActivity there is a method:--public void set(String[] navMenuTitles, TypedArray navMenuIcons)

Comment: That what in your extension: FirstActivity extends Activity

Comment: I ma sorry..It was a mistake..I have updated..but not working

Comment: I never used this approach but if you call         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_test); in tour FirstActivity does 
 isn't it conflict with         setContentView(R.layout.drawer);
 in BaseActivity?

Comment: Nopes..This is used as container..